# how to connect and display data from wordpress database

Tags: php, wordpress, database-connection

UPDATED

I tried to use this script but it doesn't appear to be working.  Could someone provide a simple working example of how to connect to a database, retrieve data and print it out?

The script prints out Database connection working and it prints out the id but I'm not able to get the mysqli_fetch_array working and after the connection is closed doesn't print out that the database is closed

```
<?php
require( 'wp-load.php' );
$local = 'xxxxxxx';
$user  = 'xxxxxxx';
$pass  = 'xxxxxxx';
$data  = 'xxxxxxx';

$testConnection  = mysqli_connect($local,$user,$pass, $data); 

if (!$testConnection) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL);
}
echo 'Database connection working!';


global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT *  FROM  $wpdb->options" );

foreach ( $result as $row ){
   echo $row->option_id .'<br/>';       
}

$row=array();
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
print_r($row);


// Associative array
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row["option_id"],$row["option_name"]);

mysqli_close($testConnection);

 if (!$testConnection) {
    echo "database closed";
 }

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I reread your code. It seems that all you want is reading all options' `option_id` and `option_name` from the table `options`. Since `$wpdb` has handled all the connection for you, you don't need `mysqli_connect`.

The following code should work for you. I tested it on my WordPress blog, and it works.

```
<?php
require( 'wp-load.php' );

global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT *  FROM  $wpdb->options" );

foreach ( $result as $row ){
  printf ("%s (%s)<br />", $row->option_id, $row->option_name);
}
```

And here is a screenshot of my results.

[image]

---

Old Answer:

Base on WordPress document [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), `$wpdb` is an instantiation of the *wpdb* class defined in /wp-includes/wp-db.php. To use it, you need to load the core functionality of WordPress by putting the following code in front of your code:

```
require( 'wp-load.php' );
```

Comment: doesn't do anything

Comment: @DCR I changed my answer and tested my code on my server. It should work now. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @iLtc this is the right answer. I upvoted it but unfortunately it only cancels a undeserved down vote that someone gave you. I just want to let you know that you did do good work.